# Repository Pattern Update Entity and set exclusive property

Tags: c#, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

I'm using generic repository pattern with unit of work. And I'm updating record and I have one column which stored status of the record and it's not coming from view itself. So when I'm updating record I want to set just that value from repository but I can't take properties of entity. Here is my sample code to update my record.
T has isDeleted property and it's null, but I want to set that value here.
How can I do that?

```
public void QuickUpdate(T original, T updated)
{
    _dbSet.Attach(original);
    _context.Entry(original)
                .CurrentValues
                .SetValues(updated);
    _context.Entry(original).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
```

Comment: Did I understand correctly that you just want to set one flag on the entity with the method?

Comment: Yea, T updated has IsDeleted property and its null, I want to update that value to true.

Comment: So have you tried pulling the entity in question from your dbcontext by primary key or other property, make changes and save? Would this be a solution to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer.
-- Updated.

```
var originalStatus = original.GetType().GetProperty("isDeleted").GetValue(original);
updated.GetType().GetProperty("isDeleted").SetValue(original, true);

_dbSet.Attach(original);
_context.Entry(original)
            .CurrentValues
            .SetValues(updated);
_context.Entry(original).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your object model, but I'm making the simplest example I can. Let's assume for example a `Record` type for your `T` and an `Id` property for a key.

```
public void QuickUpdate(Record original)
{
    Record updatedRecord = _dbSet.Records.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Id == original.Id);
    updateRecord.IsDeleted = true;
    _dbSet.SaveChanges();
}
```

I don't quite follow your question on how the `original` and `updated` play together, but setting a single property on an entity is as simple as that.

Comment: Nope, I have a generic repository so I can't do that. But I fixed my problem. Thanks.